# lubuntu 11.10 won't let me change desktop to LXDE. Auto login, so no login screen

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, lxde

I have an older PC, switched to Ubuntu 11.10, love it but with a little research decided to switch to lubuntu for better performance. Can't load the LXDE desktop per  forum instructions because I enabled autologin at install.

Answer (score 2):

You should still be able to log out and log in again with whatever desktop you like.

In any case, you should also be able to choose `Login Screen` from the `Administration` menu (under `System`) and change the autologin process to match what you think it should be. I recommend turning off autologin.

From the `Login Screen Settings` window, you can also select whatever session you want: you could select LXDE from here to make an autologin into LXDE permanent; I'd recommend just turning off autologin instead.

Comment: There is no Administration menu in Sytem

Comment: Got to login screen, no menu to change desktop, tried right click, left click, double click....how do I get this drop down?

Comment: It'll say something like `Change Session` and perhaps a filled-in drop-down menu with something like `Ubuntu Unity` or `Gnome Classic` or `Gnome Session` or something.

Comment: Here's two examples: one from [OMGUbuntu](http://cdn.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/screen-shot-2011-12-13-at-11.43.57-500x324.jpg) for 11.10 and on [WebUpd8](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TZOfPyzCPbI/AAAAAAAADxQ/KvqXClJ6bIs/s400/regular-ubuntu11.04-desktop.png) for 11.04.

Comment: Sorry I see nothing like that, and can't seem to make any menus or drop down selections pop up no matter what I try

Comment: Did you look at the graphic links I chose? Did you click on the gearwheel?

Comment: Yes to both, no selections available. OMG, it worked when I clicked the gear wheel that time. THANK YOU!

Comment: Any suggestion on what do if I'm on a netbook and LXDE is off the bottom of the screen when I try to select the session type (the top of the list is full of various versions of Gnome and KDE that I don't know how to uninstall.)

Comment: I'd try using the arrow keys to scroll down... often the "disappearance" of the end of the list is accounted for, and using up/down arrows will get you to those options. Even if you can't see it, you should still be able to select the option this way.